# How to change existing UI screen to my own UI screen?

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call, telephonymanager

I am writing a code for Dialing calls. I am using my own UI (i.e display screen), when i touch a button on the screen for dial button, it is dialing but the existing dialing screen is displayed. I want my own screen to be displayed where i use a button to end a call.Can any one tell me how can i get my own screen displayed instead of the existing screen.I have used the following code:

```
Uri parsedPhoneNumber = Uri.parse("tel:" + number);

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, parsedPhoneNumber);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void call() {
try {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
    startActivity(callIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("helloandroid dialing example", "Call failed", e);
}
}
```

Comment: hi i have tried with this code, but still its going to existing android calling screen. how to remove that existing screen and there my own layout should be placed.. how to do it? please help me in this

Comment: hi Rajani this the only to make call